# Format a string in SpecFlow using Step Argument Conversion

Tags: c#, specflow

I wanted to know if it is possible to convert a string to another string using the Step Argument Conversion. Here is an example:

I have steps like:

`When in element 'Element' I enter 'value'`

Those steps have to accept different data, like a number, a date and so on. Their definition are like this:

```
    [When(@"in element '(.*)' I enter '(.*)'")]
    public void WhenIEnterInElement(string element, string value)
    {
        Enter(value, element);
    }
```

I would like it to accept things like:

`When in element "Element" I enter "today plus 3 days"`

And use a Step Argument Conversion like:

```
    [StepArgumentTransformation(@"today plus (\d+) days")]
    public string ConvertDate(int days)
    {
        return DateTime.Today.AddDays(days).ToString();
    }
```

It isn't working because I'm trying to convert a string to a srting am I right? Isn't there a way to do this with Step Argument Conversion?

Comment: Do you actually want to enter "today plus n days" in the input box? I would think the result should be a DateTime (the parameter "value" should be a DateTime). Or did I misunderstand what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you *really* want is to reformat a string, so that you can restrict yourself to a single binding method.

But

> The following conversions can be performed by SpecFlow (in the following precedence):
>
> no conversion, if the argument is an instance of the parameter type (e.g. the parameter type is object or string)
>
> step argument transformation
>
> standard conversion

(From https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Step-Argument-Conversions)

Since your method takes a string parameter, *no stepargumenttransformations will be used*.

You have 2 options

1) use transformations for each data type and a method binding for each type

```
[When(@"in element '(.*)' I enter '(.*)'")]
public void WhenIEnterInElement(string element, DateTime value)
{
    Enter(value, element.ToString());
}

[StepArgumentTransformation(@"today plus (\d+) days")]
public DateTime ConvertDate(int days)
{
    return DateTime.Today.AddDays(days);
}
```

2) Wrap `string` for the purposes of being able to reuse your step bindings with different unparsed data

```
public class WrappedString
{
    public string Value;
    public WrappedString(string value):Value(value) {}
}

[When(@"in element '(.*)' I enter '(.*)'")]
public void WhenIEnterInElement(string element, WrappedString value)
{
    Enter(value, element.Value);
}

[StepArgumentTransformation(@"today plus (\d+) days")]
public WrappedString ConvertDate(int days)
{
    return new WrappedString(DateTime.Today.AddDays(days).ToString());
}
```

1) is perhaps cleaner, but it sounds like your scenario is based a little around being able to manipulate text - in which case (2) may even help model that requirement.

Comment: note that using "datetime.today" in tests can lead to itermittant failures - e.g. at the end of the month (particularly february).  A test that fails/passes today should fail/pass tomorrow.